# Apache mod_rewrite rule to map the homepage to a specific file

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

So...
I have a website "www.example.com", based on Wordpress, hosted on Apache 2.4.
I want to redirect the home page to a specific file. When I say "redirect" I mean that I want to serve a specific file from the file system, not to send a HTTP 30x redirect to the client.

To be more clear, when a client request http://www.example.com/ I want to serve the file `site/hp.html`, where **site** is a subdirectory of the `DocumentRoot`

Here is the relevant section of the `.htaccess` conf file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# ==============================================
# here starts the section to serve the homepage
# from file site/hp.html
# ==============================================

RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site/hp.html [L]

# ==============================================
# here starts the standard wordpress .htaccess
# ==============================================
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

The problem is that, with this configuration, the server is processing the request via the `index.php`
If I change the line

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site/hp.html [L]
```

with

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.anothersite.com [L,R=302]
```

and exec a `curl http://www.example.com/` the server sends a redirect to `www.anothersite.com`

If I change the line

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test$
```

and exec a `curl http://www.example.com/test` the server serves the page `site/hp.html`

If I leave only the 2 rules

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site/hp.html [L]
```

and exec `curl http://www.example.com/` the server server serves the index.php page.

while running `curl http://www.example.com/anything` the server returns a 404

I'm a bit lost... I bet that there is something stupid that I'm missing... Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: With only these 2 rules `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site/hp.html [L]` what's happening when you hit home page url? Could you please do let know, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I updated the question